# cmake is already in PATH, why does QT still say "no CMake executable was found in the path"

Tags: macos, qt, cmake

My OS is MAC and I am trying to configure a project.
I installed cmake using `brew install cmake`.

cmake is installed and is on the PATH:

```
cjdeMacBook-Pro:~ cjz$ which cmake
/usr/local/bin/cmake
cjdeMacBook-Pro:~ cjz$ echo $PATH
/anaconda2/bin:/Users/cjz/dcm4che-5.10.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

As we can see, cmake is already in `$PATH`, but when I try to config the project, QT says that "no CMake executable was found in the path"

What is going on?

Comment: Have you restarted Qt Creator (I assume you're using)? From a shell where the `PATH` is correct?

Comment: Do you have any kit in `Options->Build&Run->Kits`?

Comment: I have somewhat heavily edited your question to improve the English and (I think) to improve the formatting.  If you don't like any of my changes, feel free to roll them back.  I have also removed the C++ and Linux tags because they are neither of them relevant to the question ... but I *have* added the Qt tag.

Comment: I'm almost prepared to bet real money (possibly as much as 0.01€) that @Someprogrammerdude is correct.  If so, I suggest you write that as the answer - so that the next time somebody hits this problem, they can find the solution with Google.

Comment: thank you for your help. I am not sure whether it is because of the version of my QT, I cannot find Tools on it. I am now downing form QT official website. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

in QtCreator goto **Tools -> Options... -> Build & Run** click on **Cmake** tab and look if your cmake found. If not add it there.

If you still have this error. Open your **project settings -> Build -> Build Environment** click on **details** and look there if the PATH variable is correct.

If you still have this error. Build project from shell and use some verbosity options to see more output for your error.

Answer (score 0):

For MacOSX an installer is available. It is quite easy to use it and to update your CMake installation. The app is installed into `Applications`.

Go to QtCreator -> Options -> Build & Run -> Tab CMake. Add an entry or select the current one. On the bottom set the path by using the `Select...` button. Just choice the CMake app. That's all.